# PHP RSS reader - multiple category tags

Tags: php, rss, categories

So i am using this function:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {  
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  
    echo "<ul>";  
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {  
        echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
        echo "<li>Category:" . $entry->category . "</li>";
    }  
    echo "</ul>";  
}
```

The RSS feed i'm using has multiple values for "category".
How do i retrieve all of them?

Like shown below

```
<category>Cat 1</category>
<category>Cat 2</category>
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us the RSS you're trying to parse - then we can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {  
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  
    echo "<ul>";  
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {  
        echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
        foreach($entry->category as $writeMe)
            echo "<li>Category:" . $writeMe . "</li>";
    }  
    echo "</ul>";  
}
```

Comment: I was going in that direction, but details you know, details!

Comment: what do you mean? what details?

Comment: Eg. More detail = a better possible answer.

Comment: I almost had the same thing written.. But yeah small misstypes.
Well your always helpfull in here - thx
Will accept your answer in a few minutes !

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
echo "<li>Category:" . $entry->category . "</li>";
```

with:

```
foreach($entry->category as $category) {
    echo "<li>Category:" . $category . "</li>";
}
```

But could you provide the XML structure? It should be:

```
<categories>
    <category>Cat 1</category>
    <category>Cat 2</category> 
</categories>
```